# Log4j - SetLevel to Error but INFO / DEBUG Log Still Appear

Tags: java, scala, logging, apache-spark, log4j

Using `scala` and `spark`, i try to build simple apps. To avoid too many logs, i have setLevel Log to `Level.ERROR`, but it seems all log still appear. Here're my codes :

```
import org.apache.log4j.{BasicConfigurator, Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

/**
  * Created by hduser on 16/08/16.
  */
object ALS_Test {

  def main(command : Array[String]): Unit =
  {

    Logger.getRootLogger
    Logger.getLogger(this.getClass).setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    Logger.getLogger("org.spark_project").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    BasicConfigurator.configure()

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("AppName").setMaster("local[4]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

    println("test 123")
  }
}
```

The Output when running still have many confused logs :

```
0 [main] INFO org.apache.spark.SparkContext  - Running Spark version 2.0.0
163 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory  - field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.loginSuccess with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(always=false, about=, sampleName=Ops, type=DEFAULT, value=[Rate of successful kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds)], valueName=Time)
175 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory  - field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.loginFailure with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(always=false, about=, sampleName=Ops, type=DEFAULT, value=[Rate of failed kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds)], valueName=Time)
176 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory  - field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.getGroups with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(always=false, about=, sampleName=Ops, type=DEFAULT, value=[GetGroups], valueName=Time)
177 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl  - UgiMetrics, User and group related metrics
555 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell  - Failed to detect a valid hadoop home directory
java.io.IOException: HADOOP_HOME or hadoop.home.dir are not set.
```

Comment: Try to put the `BasicConfigurator.configure()` call before you set the Level.

Comment: @Fildor i just try it. but the log still appear...

Comment: I just saw the logs come from org.apache.hadoop. You don't set that logger to ERROR level, only your project's output and the ALS_Test output. You can try either setting the rootlogger to ERROR Level or also set logger "org.apache" to ERROR-Level.

Comment: By the way: I suggest using a config file instead of doing this programmatically.